# history.js state not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, history.js

I am using the [history.js](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/) script to manage HTML5 history state changes. My code works fine in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, but I cannot get it to work in IE9. I have tried both the history.js and also history.iegte8.min.js scripts available from the github site.

The reason I chose this script was because it follows the same syntax as the proper HTML5 API which means minimal changes when users eventually get to IE10.

Here is the code.

```
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/history.iegte8.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $(window).bind('popstate', function( e ) {

            var historyState = history.state;
            if ( historyState ) {
                loadContent(historyState.link)
            } else {
                // Open Business Unit Reporting folder
                $('#item-2').prop('checked',true);
            }
        });         

        $('li a').click(function(e) {
            var latestLink = '<li>' + getLabelHierarchy(this) + '<a href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></li>';
            var historyList = latestLink + $('#historyList').html();
            history.replaceState({link: historyList}, null, null);              
        });

        $(window).trigger( "popstate" );

    });

    function getLabelHierarchy(node) {
                << code omitted >>
    }

    function loadContent(links) {
        $('#historyList').append(links);
    }


</script>
```

Has anyone used this script in IE9?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Fyi: that version of jQuery you should be using `on`, not `bind`. It will not do anything to fix your bug.

Comment: the developer of the library tries to find out what the eventhandlers for hashchanged and popstate are and raises them himself. In his sample on https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API the order of the includes is _history.js_ then _jquery.js_. try that order.

Answer (score 0):

When you use History js, it is capital H, not lower case h when working with the history, you are using the window.history, not the history.js History object.

You need to use [`getState()`](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/README.md)

```
var historyState = History.getState();
```

You also need to use History whereever else you are referencing it. Read the readme for History.js.

Comment: No dice unfortunately. I think you are referring to History.js whereas I am using the [HTML5-History-API] (https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/) Nice thing with the script that I am trying to use is that it follows the HTML5 history syntax. Checking the source it may work for IE8 but looks like it expects IE9 to support the History API which it does not. 

I may need to use History.js at the end of the day.